Pass data from server action to server component
i'm trying to pass data in my nextJS14 app from my create server action to my Home server component, specifically the value of the temperature variable so i can display it in the the jsx of my Home server component, how do I do that please.
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import ProductCard from "./components/ProductCard";
import Search from "./components/Search";

interface latLong {
  latitude: string;
  longitude: string;
}
//server action
export async function create(data: string) {
  console.log(data);
  if (data != "") {
    const apiKey = "123456";
    const geoLocationRes = await fetch(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${data}&appid=${apiKey}`
    );
    const geoLocation = await geoLocationRes.json();
    console.log(geoLocation);

    const getLocation: latLong = {
      latitude: geoLocation[0].lat,
      longitude: geoLocation[0].lat,
    };
    const currentWeatherRes = await fetch(
      ` https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${getLocation.latitude}&lon=${getLocation.longitude}&appid=${apiKey}&units={metric}`
    );
    const currentWeather = await currentWeatherRes.json();
    console.log(currentWeather);

    const temperature = currentWeather.main.temp;
    // console.log(temperature);
    // console.log("input!!");
  } else {
    console.log("no input value");
  }
}
//server component
export default async function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Display Temperature here</h1>

      <Search />
    </>
  );
}

const Search = () => {
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState("");

  const OnClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    create(inputVal);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setInputVal(e.target.value)} />
        <button type="button" onClick={OnClick}>
          click
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );


Simply call the function within your component, awaiting the value.
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import ProductCard from "./components/ProductCard";
import Search from "./components/Search";

interface latLong {
  latitude: string;
  longitude: string;
}
//server action
export async function create(data: string) {
  console.log(data);
  if (data != "") {
    const apiKey = "123456";
    const geoLocationRes = await fetch(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${data}&appid=${apiKey}`
    );
    const geoLocation = await geoLocationRes.json();
    console.log(geoLocation);

    const getLocation: latLong = {
      latitude: geoLocation[0].lat,
      longitude: geoLocation[0].lat,
    };
    const currentWeatherRes = await fetch(
      ` https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${getLocation.latitude}&lon=${getLocation.longitude}&appid=${apiKey}&units={metric}`
    );
    const currentWeather = await currentWeatherRes.json();

    const temperature = currentWeather.main.temp;
    return temperature;
  } else {
    console.log("no input value");
  }
}
//server component
export default async function Home() {
  // Don't forget to pass in whatever data should go to the server action
  const temp = await create();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Display Temperature here</h1>
      <p>{temp}</p>
      <Search />
    </>
  );
}


thank you for your reply and answer, but i have one more question how do i pass the value of my argument for the function i called in the Home component from a child component which in this case is the Search component?

@AbdullahiAbbas Are you referring to the temp variable?  If so, you would simply pass it as a prop to the Search component like so: <Search temperature={temp} />.  Then in the declaration of the Search component you would access it: export default async function Search({ temperature }).

what i meant is i want to get the Input value from my Search component and use it as the argument when i call the create function from my Home component

@AbdullahiAbbas you can't do that exactly.  Server actions run on the server, meaning that you won't be able to accept user input directly and pass that input to server actions.  What you should probably do instead is have the Search component set query parameters and parse those in the server action.  If you don't know how to do that you should make a new question on Stack Overflow because that's out of the scope of your original question.

ah that makes sense, I'll look up how to do that so i can use it and if i get stuck ill post a new question, thank you so much for all your help i really appreciate it

No problem!  And don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it solved your original question.
